# Convert flat list to associative list or dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I currently have a list which looks like the following:

```
['item01', 'item02', 'item03']
```

I want to convert it to something like this (demo in JSON):

```
[
    {"title":"item01"},
    {"title":"item02"},
    {"title":"item03"}
]
```

I'm fairly new to Python so, I'm not really sure what to even search for to figure this out.

Comment: So you want a Python data structure where any given key can map onto several different values?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I will ultimately be POSTing off the data as a JSON string via requests. Each sub list will definitely have a title key and may add a `date` too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list comprehesion:

```
input = ['item01', 'item02', 'item03']
output = [{"title":x} for x in input]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)